# c++ double initialization- default values?

Tags: c++

I'm debugging some C++ code, and have come across a double that never appears to have been given a value. It is declared with the line

```
double x;
```

Having not used C or C++ much before, I'm unsure whether doubles have a value that they default to? I.e. Given the declaration above, if `x` is never specifically given a value, will it automatically be 0, or will it be `null`?

The `x` is used in a calculation elsewhere in the code, and the result of the calculation is meant to be displayed to the user - at the moment it's not... The calculation is:

```
y * asin(sin(x / y) * sin(a * b));
```

I would assume that if `x` defaults to 0, this would cause a compile/runtime error? If `x` defaults to 0, surely the calculation would return 0, and 0 would be displayed to the user?

Comment: declarations of type `double x;` do not assign default value to x (what exactly is default value anyway ?) if the declaration is inside a function's scope ! you must write it yourself `double x = 0.0;`

Comment: Is it inside some functions?

Comment: @Raxvan: unless it's static storage duration :-)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Comment: why would displaying 0 to the user cause a runtime error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on *where* the variable is declared.

If it's declared as a global variable then it will be zero-initialized before `main` starts running.

If it's declared as a non-static local variable inside a function then its value is indeterminate (in reality it will be whatever is in the memory occupied by the variable, it will be seemingly random).

Using uninitialized (non-static) local variables leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If declared as a `static` local variable, then it will also be zero-initialized in the first call to the function.

Comment: what if it's a member of a class?

Comment: @athos Then it depends on where the containing object were declared, and what initialization the class does to the member.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't specify an initialization value then the value for  `double x` is undefined if it's on the heap/stack. If it's a global variable it will be set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> 1. For every named variable with static or thread-local storage duration that is not subject to constant initialization (since C++14), before any other initialization.
> 2. As part of value-initialization sequence for non-class types and for members of value-initialized class types that have no constructors, including value initialization of elements of aggregates for which no initializers are provided.
> 3. When an array of any character type is initialized with a string literal that is too short, the remainder of the array is zero-initialized.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

So double data members in classes with no constructors will be initialized to zero.

Comment: *"in classes"* Only if the whole class is value-initialized.